# Unit Test Method for a database connection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Could any one suggest how to write unit test method for this method?

```
public virtual void OpenDatabaseConnection(string connectionString)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think Microsoft has already and sufficiently tested all these classes for you .....

Comment: Why do you think it is needed to test this piece of code?

Comment: @marc_s: I don't think (s)he wants to test the connection class, but rather, that it's properly used in the method.

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing is to test your code, not a third party's code. That would be part of an integration test.

However, if you personally wrote the `SqlConnection` class, and would like to test that it works correctly, I would suggest mocking out the external dependencies and then verifying that the external dependency (a database driver for example) was called when you executed the `Open` method.

Another note on your example: the method you show will open the connection and then `Dispose` of it since you have a `using` statement around it. In other words, there is no way to use the connection once opened and the method itself is a no-op to an outside caller.

Answer (score 1):

You could inject a connection factory of some sorts (e.g., `Func<IDbConnection>`), make it return a mock, and then assert that `Open()` and `Dispose(`) were called on the mock.

And of course all that only makes sense, if you actually use the connection for anything but opening and then disposing it, as rae1 correctly pointed out in his answer.